# Loading a document into a Webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Am trying to load a .docx file into the uiwebview and am displaying it.To load the document into the webview it takes some fraction of seconds so i can see a white blank screen before the content can appear on the screen.I don't want to see that white screen while loading instead of that i want to do some actions like activity indicator or changing the background.How can i achieve this please help me.
Here is my code;

```
   -(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webViews
       {
  webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];
isWebviewLoaded=YES;
    webView.delegate=self;
    webView.alpha=0;

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SKIN   ADVISORuser_updated.docx" ofType:nil];
    //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"UserGuidelines3.html" ofType:nil];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

      [webViews loadRequest:request];
}
```

and in viewdidload am calling above method:

```
[self loadDocument:@"ADVISORuser_updated.docx" inView:self.webView];
```

Even am implementing a delegate method to change the background but delegate is not executing

```
      - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewload {
     if (isWebviewLoaded) 
     {
    isWebviewLoaded = NO;
     webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"Instructions Screen Background light_PNG.png"]];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"webView" context:nil];
       webView.alpha = 1.0;
       [UIView commitAnimations];
         }
     }
```

Please can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewload {
```

will be called only if you have set the delegate for the webView (in the xib &.h file)

Answer (score 0):

before loadRequest u could create UIActivityIndicator object and start it by calling start method

and in webView delegate didFinishLoading: & didFailwithError method suspend the activity indicator